# How can I jump back to the page previously viewed in evince?

Tags: evince

When viewing a pdf file in my evince (42.3), I couldn't find a way to jump back to the page previously viewed. I remember there used to be a button somewhere for that purpose, but I can't find it any longer. How can I jump back to the page just previously viewed? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for "previous page visited". You can find these keybindings in the Help screen that you can show with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>.

Comment: I meant the page previously viewed, not necessarily the previous page

Comment: I corrected this. You instead could have found it yourself because, in addition to suggesting a key binding, I indicated how to find keybindings yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In the Evince keyboard shortcuts it appears to be assigned to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>/<kbd>Back</kbd>

[image]